# Minipage for table in IEEE not extending to full coloumn

Tags: tables, minipage

I am using a minipage to contain a table in the IEEE class. The problem is that the table does not extend to the whole column and somewhat appears short. 
Here is a reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        \toprule
        T & X &  Y & Z\\
        \midrule
        A &   $1$ & $1$\footnote{foot} & $2$ \\
        B &  $2$ & $1$ & $1$\\
        C & $2$ & $1$ & $1$  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `minipage` environment does not stretch the content, it limits the width of it's content!

Comment: If you like to have table over two column. than use `table*`.

Comment: Is there any way I can stretch the table to contain the full (one) column width?

Comment: yes: use `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{<columns type<} ... \end{tabularx}` or `\begin{tabular*}{\columnswidth} {...} ...\end{tabular*}`. In the first case the column width is automatically determined, in second not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tabular` is set at its natural width. You seem to need the `minipage` for the footnote, so I kept it.

You can use the `tabular*` environment, with the `\extracolsep` feature.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]

\caption{A caption to the table}\label{capt}

\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc}
\toprule
T & X &  Y & Z\\
\midrule
A & $1$ & $1$\footnote{foot} & $2$ \\
B & $2$ & $1$ & $1$\\
C & $2$ & $1$ & $1$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As starting point can serve the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{*{4}{C}}
    \toprule
T & X &  Y & Z\\
    \midrule
A & $1$ & $1$\footnote{foot}    & $2$   \\
B & $2$ & $1$                   & $1$   \\
C & $2$ & $1$                   & $1$  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With it you will get:

[image]

In above MWE the vertical lines are omitted since they looks with `booktabs` rules very ugly.

Comment: The problem is the minipage around the table. I need the minipage for the footnote to be at the end of the table, rather than at the end of page

Comment: I see, than you just return `minipage` as you have in your MWE. I will correct my answer accordingly.